# Unable to Map URL's in django application

Tags: django

I am trying my hands on django. I have a Django project, in which I have an attributes app. I have added a model class called Attributes

```
class Attributes(models.Model):

    attr1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)        

    attr2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)        

    attr3 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

. In that, I have a view called index, which lists down the attribute records. I am using a template which prints the list and points to the view corresponding to the properties of that record.

```
def index(request):
    list = Attributes.objects.all()
    context = {'list' : list}
    return render(request, 'attributes/index.html', context)

def listattr(request, val):
    obj = Attributes.objects.filter(attr1=val).get()
    context = {'idp_object' : idp_obj}
    return render(request, 'attributes/properties.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<val>\d+)/$', views.listattr, name='listattr'))
```

I get the list when i navigate to 127.0.0.1/attributes, but when I click on any link, I get an error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in testapplication.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
attributes/ ^$ [name='index']
attributes/ ^(?P<val>\d+)/$ [name='listattr']
```

am i mapping the URL's in an incorrect way? If yes, what is the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get individual `Attribute` instance by `id` and not by `attr1`:

```
def listattr(request, val):
    obj = Attributes.objects.filter(id=val).get()
    context = {'idp_object' : idp_obj}
    return render(request, 'attributes/properties.html', context)
```

BTW, it is better to use `get_object_or_404` shortcut in the first line of your view:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def listattr(request, val):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Attributes, id=val)
    context = {'idp_object' : obj}
    return render(request, 'attributes/properties.html', context)
```

Comment: attr1 is a string passed on by the link. in any case, the url is not getting matched

Comment: Url is mismatched because of `^(?P<val>\d+)/$` regex. It catches digits only.

Comment: oops. yeah. that sounds about right. scratched my head for the past couple of hours. thanks..:)